# How to show empty rows and not custom message in Datatables if there is no matching search

Tags: regex, datatables, rows

I am using Datatables in my site but i don't want at search the table to be shrinked.

As far as my research went i only could find how i can change the message "No matching records found" at my custom message.

If there is no matching result i want to be displayed 5 empty rows.

How to display empty rows if there is no matching search in Datatables?

Table initialization

```
$(document).ready(function() {
generateListEmployee("table.display");
generateNoSort("table.display2");

});

function generateListEmployee(tableId) {
$(tableId).dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength" : 5,
    "sDom" : '<"dashboardTable"t><"#paggination"p><"#search-container"f>',
    "pagingType" : "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "" },
});

$('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Search");

}
```

Table HTML

```
<div id="all-employees-table-wraper">
                        <table id="all-employees-table" class="table table-hover display">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name, Surname</th>
                                    <th>Initiative(s)</th>
                                    <th>Position</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tiger Nixon1</td>
                                    <td>System Architect1</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-01"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-02"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-03"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tiger Nixon2</td>
                                    <td>System Architect2</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-01"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-02"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-03"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tiger Nixon3</td>
                                    <td>System Architect3</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-01"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-02"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-03"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tiger Nixon4</td>
                                    <td>System Architect4</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-01"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-02"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-03"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tiger Nixon5</td>
                                    <td>System Architect5</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-01"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-02"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-03"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tiger Nixon1</td>
                                    <td>System Architect1</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-01"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-02"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-03"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tiger Nixon2</td>
                                    <td>System Architect2</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-01"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-02"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-03"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tiger Nixon3</td>
                                    <td>System Architect3</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-01"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-02"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-03"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tiger Nixon4</td>
                                    <td>System Architect4</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-01"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-02"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-03"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tiger Nixon5</td>
                                    <td>System Architect5</td>
                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-01"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-02"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="dashboard_icons-03"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Please, provide some code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What version of datatables are you using? (1.9.x or 1.10.x)?